# Discrepancy in Proof of π's Transcendence

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, pi, transcendental-numbers

Consider the following:

"From the Weaker Hermite-Lindemann-Weierstrass Theorem, $e^{iπ}$ is transcendental.

However, from Euler's Identity:
$$e^{iπ} = −1$$

which is the root of $h(z) = z+1$

and so is algebraic. This contradicts the conclusion that $e^{iπ}$ is transcendental. Hence by Proof by Contradiction it must follow that $π$ is transcendental."

Monic, minimal polynomial expressions are of degree two. When no such polynomial exists for an irrational number it is deemed transcendental. Note that $e^{iπ} = −1$ is the root of a ***linear equation***: $h(z) = z+1$. How is this possible? Logically, $e^{iπ} = −1$ should be the root of a quadratic equation in order for the contradiction to be warranted. Doesn't this call into question the proof of $π$ transcendence?

Comment: Not following.  All rationals are algebraic, of degree $1$.

Comment: Who said "$e^{i\pi} $ is transcendental"? Both $e, \pi$ are transcendental, but $e^{i\pi} =-1$ is a rational number.

Answer (score 1):

As it was pointed out already, it is allowed in the theory for the minimal polynomial to be linear.

If you do not like this, you can reach a contradiction by observing that
$$
e^{ i \frac{\pi}{2}}=i
$$
is algebraic with minimal polynomial $x^2+1$. This implies that $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is transcendental, and it is easy to show that implies that $\pi$ must also be transcendental.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. It is not true that all minimal monic polynomials are of degree $2$. Precisely, $x+1$, the minimal polynomial of $-1$, has degree $1$. There are minimal polynomials of any degree.